# How long do session cookies last on Android/iOS devices?

Tags: ios, mobile, cookies, session-state

As I understand it, if I have code that creates a cookie without an explicit expiry time, it lasts for the duration of the browsing session (e.g. until the user closes their browser).

How does this apply to mobile devices, specifically iOS, where you never *really* quit Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies in Safari on the iPhone are stored in a property list file.
They stay there until the user manually clears their cookies on their device.

Comment: Thanks, is this documented somewhere or derived from your own personal discovery?

Comment: After searching around, I found out that Safari stores its cookies in the plist file. To remove them, users just go to settings for safari and delet them manually.

Comment: But does that apply to session cookies? Because, for example, rebooting an iPad loses all session cookies, whereas putting it to stand by does not, so I dont think that assumption is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, if I have code that creates a cookie without an explicit expiry time, it lasts for the duration of the browsing session (e.g. until the user closes their browser).

Comment: There's no such thing as "closing" browser (or any app) on iOS and Android. Apps can be only switched and unloaded in background. Even when unloaded and loaded again, some state is usually preserved. Safari and Chrome preserves open tabs.